# CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE in cv2.GaussianBlur()

Tags: opencv, opencl

I used OpenCV v4.0.1.
The following is the test python code

```
import cv2
img = cv2.UMat(cv2.imread("image.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR))
imgUMat = cv2.UMat(img)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(imgUMat, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 1.5)
gray = cv2.Canny(gray, 0, 50)

cv2.imwrite('test.jpg',img)
cv2.imwrite('test_UMat.jpg' , imgUMat)
```

It returned some error message as below

```
[ WARN:0] Using world accessible cache directory. This may be not secure: /var/tmp/
OpenCL error CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE (-54) during call: clEnqueueNDRangeKernel('row_filter_C1_D0', dims=2, globalsize=128x528x1, localsize=16x16x1) sync=false
[     1]     25: FMA_MUL         temp(322).dp.x, 2.000000, temp(319).dp.x
```

I checked my OpenCL

```
root@imx6qsabresd:/usr/opencv_test# opencv_version --opencl
4.0.1
OpenCL Platforms:
    Vivante OpenCL Platform
        iGPU: Vivante OpenCL Device GC2000.5108.0000 (OpenCL 1.1 )
Current OpenCL device:
    Type = iGPU
    Name = Vivante OpenCL Device GC2000.5108.0000
    Version = OpenCL 1.1
    Driver version = OpenCL 1.1 V6.2.4.p1.150331
    Address bits = 32
    Compute units = 4
    Max work group size = 1024
    Local memory size = 1 KB
    Max memory allocation size = 32 MB
    Double support = No
    Host unified memory = Yes
    Device extensions:
        cl_khr_byte_addressable_store
        cl_khr_gl_sharing
    Has AMD Blas = No
    Has AMD Fft = No
    Preferred vector width char = 4
    Preferred vector width short = 4
    Preferred vector width int = 4
    Preferred vector width long = 0
    Preferred vector width float = 4
    Preferred vector width double = 0
```

"localsize=16x16x1" is less than the "Max work group size = 1024"

"globalsize=128x528x1" is evenly divisable by the "localsize=16x16x1"

I don't know why it returned the error "CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE". So I checked the code line by line, and I found the error caused by cv2.GaussianBlur(). By the way, if I don't use UMat, the cv2.GaussianBlur() would not cause any error.

Could anybody tell me the reason and how do I fix the error?

Comment: `Local memory size = 1 KB` is very, very small. Do you know how much local memory your kernel attempts to use? I realise the error code doesn't match an out of memory condition, but that could be a bug in the implementation.

Comment: I checked the document i.MX_Graphics_User's_Guide.pdf, it said: The OpenCL Embedded Profile specification defines the minimum requirement for local memory to be 1KB to pass conformance testing.

Comment: I found some info in the website : https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/OpenCL-optimizations